# Is it possible to call an external Batch file from Genexus IDE (external tool)

Tags: ide, genexus

From the Genexus IDE, I would like to call a batch file passing as an argument the Genexus project location; similar to "External Tools" in Jdeveloper, is this possible? if so, where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, to do so, you must use genexus sdk and develop an user extension to integrate it inside the IDE

Answer (score 2):

As of Genexus 15 U12, there's a new feature called Build Events https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?39474
I believe that's what you need

Comment: Almost, I need to be able to execute it without the need to build something. For example, I do some changes on a project and then want to execute my bat file. Using what you suggested I need to trigger a build. Thanks

Comment: Oh ok, in that case, the extension mentioned by Sandro would be the way to go.